# $\,s_k := x^k+y^k, \,x, y\in\Bbb R.\,$ If $\,s_1,s_2,s_3\in\Bbb Z\,$ then $\,s_n\in \Bbb Z\,$ for all $n\ge 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $x, y$ be real numbers such that the numbers $x+y,x^2+y^2$ and $x^3+y^3$ are integers. Prove that $x^n+y^n$ is an integer for all natural $n$.

---

***My attempt:*** Let $x+y=l, x^{2}+y^{2}=m$ for integers $l,m$, then $x y=\frac{l^2-m}{2}$. Now, $\begin{aligned} x^3+y^3 &=(x+y)^3-3 x y(x+y) \\ &=l^3-3 \cdot\left(\frac{l^2-m}{2}\right) \cdot l \\ &=\frac{3 m l}{2}-\frac{l^3}{2} \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\left[3 m l-l^3\right] \end{aligned}$ which is an integer, but i don't know what to do next.

Comment: @KCd well because that's how it was given in the original question, and I didn't change anything of it while posting it. Also how's this relevant at all to the problem anyway? Having parentheses or not isn't going to change anything right?

Comment: Hint: for a counterexample let $y = -x$. It seems the problem was copied incorrectly - it should be $x^4+y^4,\,$ not $x^3+ y^3,\,$ e.g. see  [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h220099p1220604) (link found by John Omielan by an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E3%2By%5E3%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5En%2By%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Areal%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1) in a deleted answer below).

Comment: Iirc the prior linked 2008 AoPS proof (post #4) also appears here in a number of places, but I could only find [one such post in 2017](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2576647/242) via a quick search. But possibly I am recalling older posts on sci.math or Ask an Algebraist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false. Take $x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Then $x+y=0,x^2+y^2=1,x^3+y^3=0$ but $x^4+y^4=\dfrac{1}{2}$.